# Change active tab viewport size like devtools responsive view

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

In a Chrome extension I want to change the viewport size, something like DevTools responsive view. I am looking into https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-ZoomSettingsMode and see methods for changing the zoom but not the actual width/height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dev Tools achieve this through [debugger protocol](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol).

You can try and emulate that, but you'll need to use [`chrome.debugger` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger).

The relevant command seems to be this: [`Emulation.setDeviceMetricsOverride`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/Emulation/#method-setDeviceMetricsOverride) - note that this is not part of the "stable" protocol and may change without warning.

Comment: Oh, this is what I need! Thank you

Comment: It would be grate to know if it will become RFC